# Should I connect 3V3 in UART

Tags: serial, raspberry-pi

My Raspberryπ has a serial console in its GPIOs. My logic level UART converter has four pins: GND, RXD, TXD and 3V3. It works without connecting 3V3.

Why should I want to connect the 3V3 pin to the Raspberryπ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the device is powered through the clamping diodes on the TxD input, since that will be higher than Vcc if you haven't that connected.

[image]

Doing so is very naughty, the diodes are meant as overvoltage protection, not for powering the device. It's not because [something works](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32990/do-i-really-need-resistors-when-controlling-leds-with-arduino) that it's wise to use it that way.

**edit** re your comment
You hadn't said anything about the USB connection! In that case the 3.3 V is *not* unconnected: it's the *output* of an on-board LDO voltage regulator, which also powers the UART converter. Chances are that it's an FTDI converter, probably an [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf). In that case the 3.3 V regulator is on the FT232R IC.

> Up to 50mA can be drawn from this pin to power external logic if required. (p. 8)

Which is OK for a small microcontroller circuit, but not for the Rpi, which needs up to 700 mA.

Comment: OK, thank you for your fast reply. It's already powered through USB.

Comment: Then you must not connect it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not connect it. That 3V3 output can no supply enough current to power a RaPi. It is used when for instance a low-current 3V3 microcontroller is connected to the usb-serial converter.